# <form> not posting all of a sudden

Tags: node.js, forms, google-chrome

I am having a strange issue that I think might be Chrome related but wanted to post here for thoughts.

I have some users who when trying to log into my node.js application, they press enter or the log in button and it just sits and spins and never times out or anything. When looking at the Network tab when this issue occurred the POST never showed up. I then put some alerts on the button click with javascript and as long as the button was in the  tag nothing showed up.

Completely deleting the users' profile (suggestion from Google) made it work...until chrome updated and then it happened again.

Using any other browser, no issues. Chrome Beta, the issue shows up. Chrome Canary, I have had 2 users testing for over a week and they have not seen the issue reappear. Incognito has the issue occur as well.

Google Support asked me to send a HAR file to them. The interesting thing was when I opened up developer tools, went to the network tab and then cleared the screen to start a recording, the issue disappeared for that moment only.

It is working for 80% of my users so I can't see how it could be a coding issue, this is also a login that I created over a year ago and have not touched since.

If anyone has any insights I would love to know what might be causing this.

Comment: Is this a google login mechanism, or your own?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not suitable for questions that cannot produce a [mcve] demonstrating the described behavior. Unless you can provide one, answering this question is more-or-less an elaborate guessing game.

Comment: As a side note, I don't see how this question would be related to [tag:node.js]. Perhaps [tag:javascript], [tag:google-chrome], [tag:form], and [tag:post] would be more relevant, but that only matters once this question is on-topic, which it currently is not due to the explanation provided in my previous comment.

Comment: @jakerella the authentications is using https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory

Comment: @PatrickRoberts You are correct, I should probably tag it in google-chrome and form. I posted it in nodejs because the application is developed in node. The irepoducibility of the issue is why I tried posting because it's honestly confounding. If the question is not suitable then it will fall to the bottom and I'll keep searching for solutions!